# numerical constants as types or variables in a container?

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr, c++17

I am wondering whether to have numerical constants as `constexpr` variables or `::std::integral_constant<>`? Example:

```
template <typename T>
struct container
{
  static constexpr ::std::size_t const size = 16;
};

template <typename T>
struct container
{
  using size = ::std::integral_constant<::std::size_t, 16>;
};
```

I lean more towards the `::std::integral_constant` approach since a static constexpr variable might require a definition in a .cpp file somewhere.

Comment: Note: The namespace 'std' is reserved, you do not need '::std'

Comment: Less is better. Do not use `std::integral_constant`.

Comment: The `value` member of `std::integral_constant` (which you need to use to access the value) is a `static constexpr`.  So in my opinion, for what you want to do, `std::integral_constant` is just a long way round to create a `constexpr`.

Comment: it happened, that a compiler wanted a definition in a .cpp file.

Comment: This is tagged C++1z - inline variables prevent ODR violations.

Comment: @DieterLücking, It can [still be a problem](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f59ff779fe3850a7), given some crappy code that some annoying person will inevitably write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally believe, the best option is old-fashioned enum. `constexpr` is prone to ODR-usage, and `integral_constant` is too much typing (you can always create one if you need it somewhere later in the code).

Comment: or, these days, enum class.

Comment: @user1095108, I do not think so. When enums are  used as integral constants within the class, enum class  just adds clutter.

Comment: give a nice small example please.

Comment: @user1095108,  example for what exactly?

Comment: write some source or provide a link to a real-life class template using this approach.

Comment: @user1095108, not trying to be pain-in-the-neck, but really unsure what you are asking. I assume,  you know how to define enums inside the class? So what type of illustration are you looking for?

Comment: @user1095108, Many people prefer to define traits like `struct trait { enum { value = 2; }; };`. Is that good enough for an example?